# app.use(restify.bodyParser()) not working as req object is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify, body-parser

I am using restify and for the HTTP POST calls the request object is always empty. Could anyone please let me know what could be the possible reason.

Regards

Comment: wrong `content-type` maybe. Common mistake is sending `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` when `application/json` is expected.

Comment: 'User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:3001
content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 38'.This is the fiddler , but same error :(

Comment: `app.use(restify.bodyParser({mapParams:false}));`. Without this config everything is decoded into `req.params`

Comment: `User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:3001
content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 43` and the request body is `{
userName:"dhuper",
password:"dhuper"
}` and now getting the error as `{"code":"InvalidContent","message":"Invalid JSON: Unexpected token u"}`

Comment: it's not correct json. It's valid javascript - not JSON. Should be: `{ "userName":"dhuper", "password":"dhuper" }`

Comment: `User-Agent: Fiddler
content-type: application/json
Host: localhost:3001
Content-Length: 51` and the json as `{
  "userName":"dhuper",
  "password":"dhuper"
}` . using above is giving me `req.params as {}`

Comment: What do you expect? What's your goal?

Answer (score 0):

You receive `"Invalid JSON: Unexpected token u"` because you are trying to parse `undefined` as JSON. To stop the request body from being `undefined` do the following:

1. Check that your code should look something like this:

   ```
   var restify = require('restify');
   var server = restify.createServer();

   // This line MUST appear before any route declaration
   server.use(restify.bodyParser());

   server.post('/customer/:id', function (req, resp, next) {
     console.log("The request body is " + req.body);
     response.send("post received. Thanks!");
     return next();
   });
   ```
2. Check that your content-type is valid. eg.

   ```
   curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST ...
   ```